# How to find tangent vector to curve (which is the intersection between two curves)

Tags: calculus, parametrization

Consider the curve C obtained by intersecting the surfaces defined by

$x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ and $x^2-y^2+z^2=1$

At the point $(1,1,1)$, what is the tangent vector to the curve?

I tried parameterizing the curve and got $(t,\pm1,\sqrt{2-t^2})$ but am lost on what to do next.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The tangent vector is perpendicular to the normals of both surfaces at the point $(1,1,1)$.  Do you know a function that gives a vector perpendicular to its inputs?

Comment: Your curve is the intersection of two surfaces, not curves.

Comment: Take the derivative of the branch of the curve that you found that goes through the point $(1,1,1)$ and then plug in the $t$ value that corresponds to that point.

Answer (score 1):

You have found both curves of intersection, clearly the one going through $(1,1,1)$ is
$$s(t)=(t, 1, \sqrt{2-t^2})$$
note that $s(1)=(1,1,1)$
$$s'(t)=(1,0, \frac {-t}{\sqrt{2-t^2}}) $$
The unit tangent vector is given by
$$\vec T = \frac{s'(1)}{||s'(1)||} $$